# How to separate a string user input into two different strings?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

Sorry for the uninformative title, but I'm new to Java and am quite confused about how I should separate a user input (a string) into two different strings.

Essentially, what I want to do is take a user input with two of the **same** numbers or letters separated by a space, and remove the corresponding numbers or letters from an ArrayList of strings.

Note: the user input can be a single number or letter, and the method for this part must identify that the user input is not a single letter or number.

For example, if I have the (java) code:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scan.nextLine();
```

the user then input:`5 5` (5 space 5)

and if I have an ArrayList:

```
Arraylist<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>;
arrList.add("1");
arrList.add("5");
arrList.add("5");
arrList.add("3");
```

How do I remove the two 5's from `arrList`?

My first approach was to separate the user input string into two different strings so that I could remove the two strings from the ArrayList of strings. Since both numbers or letters should be identical to each other, I would only need to scan the first integer or letter. However, I'm not quite sure how to write a method that would scan the first integer or letter in a string that consist of two numbers/integers with a space between them.

I would be much appreciated for any help! Thanks!

Comment: "I'm not quite sure how to write a method that would scan the first integer or letter in a string that consist of two numbers/integers with a space between them." You're looking for [string.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use [`Collection::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:

```
String number = "5";                           // or an user input
arrList.removeIf(item -> number.equals(item)); // number::equals
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` to split the inputs by space

```
String str = scan.nextLine();
String[] list = str.split(" ");
```

Then you can remove inputs using `.remove()` from ArrayList

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    arrList.remove(list[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options:

Use split():

```
String[] numbers = str.split(" ");
```

Use next() instead of nextLine():

```
String str1 = scan.next();
String str2 = scan.next();
```

If you take the latter approach, you might add a hasNext() call to handle the case where there's only one string.

Answer (score 1):

According to your explained example, it looks like you only want to remove the first instance of a string item from the ArrayList otherwise you wouldn't want to supply `5  5`, something like this:

```
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
arrList.add("1");
arrList.add("5");
arrList.add("5");
arrList.add("3");
    
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = "";
while (str.equals("")) {
    System.out.print("Enter the numerical strings to delete from ArrayList seperated by a whitespace: " + ls
           + "Your Entry: --> ");
    str = scan.nextLine(); 
    if (!str.replaceAll("\\s+", "").matches("\\d+")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry! Entries must be numerical integer type! (" + str + ")" + ls);
        str = "";
    }
}
    
String[] numbers = str.split("\\s+");
// Iterate through all the User Supplied numbers...
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    // Remove the first instance (only) of the 
    // current User the supplied number.
    for (int j = 0; j < arrList.size(); j++) {
        if (arrList.get(j).equals(numbers[i])) {
            arrList.remove(j);
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Display the ArrayList when all is done...
System.out.print(String.join(ls, arrList));
```

If you supply only one 5 then only the first 5 encountered within the ArrayList is removed.